# programming in lua, objects

Tags: class, oop, lua

Sample code:

```
function Account:new (o)
  o = o or {}   -- create object if user does not provide one
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end
```

taken from "Object-Oriented Programming: Classes" http://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html

What is the purpose of the `self.__index = self` line? And why is it executed every time an object is created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have said, `self` (the `Account` table) is used as a metatable assigned to the objects created using `new`. Simplifying slightly (more info available at the links provided) when a field is not found in 'o', it goes to the 'Account' table because o's metatable says to go to Account (this is what `__index` does).

It does not, however, need to be executed every time an object is created. You could just as easily stick this somewhere:

```
Account.__index = Account
```

and it would work as well.

The somewhat longer story is that if an object `o` has a metatable, and that metatable has the `__index` field set, then a *failed* field lookup on `o` will use `__index` to find the field (`__index` can be a table or function). If `o` has the field set, you do not go to its metatable's `__index` function to get the information. Again, though, I encourage you to read more at the links provided above.

Answer (score 6):

The Lua documentation is somewhat vague on this detail and many of the answers here either echo the Lua docs or don't thoroughly explain this confusing tidbit.

The line `self.＿index = self` is present purely for the benefit of the newly-created object, `o`; it has no meaningful or functional impact on `Account`.

The `＿index` field only has special meaning within the context of metatables; therefore `self.＿index` is just a plain old regular field for `Account`. However, when `Account` is used as a metatable for `o`, the `＿index` field "becomes" a metamethod for `o`. (So what's a field for `Account` is a metamethod for `o`.)

When you take the two statements in combination ...

```
(1)    setmetatable(o, self)
(2)    self.＿index = self
```

... you're using `Account` as the metatable for `o` on line (1) and setting the `＿index` metamethod for `o` to `Account` on line (2). (On line (2), you're also setting the "plain old field" `__index` in `Account` to `Account`.) So the useful aspect of `self.＿index = self` isn't the setting of the `＿index` field for `Account`, but rather the setting of the `＿index` metamethod for `o`.

The following is functionally equivalent:

```
    setmetatable(o, self)
    getmetatable(o).＿index = self
```

Comment: Keep in mind that while __index is a metamethod in name, lua provides a handy shortcut where __index can be assigned a table instead of a function. In these cases when __index is called a lookup is performed. Therefore, when you say __index = self what you're really saying is, if you can't find a given field in the instance of Account, look (aka "index") at the Account class/prototype itself.

Comment: Quick question: I've often seen the `self.__index = self` statement inside the `new` function, which makes me think that it is being executed for every new instance of the class. Would it not have the exact same effect if it were set only once on the base table (Account in this case)?

Answer (score 4):

Lua is not an object-oriented language, but it has all of the facilities for writing object-oriented code. However, it is done in a [prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) fashion a la [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). Instead of explicitly creating classes, a prototype object is created and then cloned to create new instances.

The `__index` metamethod is invoked to perform key lookups on read accesses to a table when the key is not already present in the table. So, `self.__index = self` essentially allows for inheritance of all methods and fields of the `Account` "class" by the new "instance" that is created in the `o = o or {}` and `setmetatable(o, self)` lines.

See also:

- [Metatables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8)
- [Metamethods Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetamethodsTutorial)
- [Inheritance Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/InheritanceTutorial)

Comment: I found this "tutorial" on Lua [inheritance](http://lua-users.org/wiki/InheritanceTutorial) particularly enlightening in conjunction with this answer.

Comment: @Indolering Thanks. I put your link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

They're used to re-direct table accesses (local y = table[key]) which are also used in method calls. In the above line, object o will have any attempts to access keys re-directed to the current object self, effortlessly inheriting all member functions. And possibly data variables too, depending on what exactly that __index is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Creating objects (which are simply Tables) is quite different with Lua.
The basic idea is to create a regular table containing attributes(functions and values) that are common to all instances. This table, I'll call CAT for Common Attributes Table.

If you reference an attribute in a table and Lua can't find this attribute, there is a way to tell Lua where else to look for the attribute. We want Lua to look in the CAT for common attributes. Metatables answer that need. More on how that works later.

We also need methods in the CAT to be able to use instance values. **Self** answers that need. When you call a table function (method) this way: `tableName:methodName()`, Lua automatically places a reference to the table object as the first parameter. The name of this parameter is self. Even though the method is located in the CAT, self will refer to the particular calling object instance table.

Say we have a CAT called Car.

```
metaCar = { __index = Car }  
-- this table will be used as the metatable for all instances of Car  
-- Lua will look in Car for attributes it can't find in the instance
```

For example:

```
-- instance table is called mustang    
-- setmetatable(mustang, metaCar)
```

Here is a general purpose function that creates new instance objects and sets the metatable for it.  If the CAT has a constructor function (init), it gets executed as well.

```
function newObj(metatable)  
..obj = {}      -- create new empty instance object  
..setmetatable(obj, metatable) –- connect the metatable to it  
..if obj.init then  -- if the CAT has an init method, execute it  
....obj:init()  
..end  
..return obj  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `setmetatable(o, self)` only set Account as metatable of `o` (otherwise **nil** by default). That's the first step of a prototype binding but it's  **NOT** enough make functions of Account searchable from `o`!

To make `o` search methods on Account, the metatable object (Account) have to include a `__index` event with the value pointing to itself, which contains prototype methods.

So it's has to be done in 2 steps:

1. create a metatable value with `__index` event
2. setmetatable to the target table.

As said in the original book, this is "a small optimization" -- you will usually need another mold table value created as metatable of `o`. But here in this case, the code re-used the Acccount table value, as both metatable and prototype object.